# 8-pin ARM JTAG interface header

Tags: arm, embedded, linux, jtag, pinout

An embedded device based on ARM926EJ-S revision 5 (ARMv5TEJ) chip.
The PCB have 8-pin test points for connecting JTAG debug interface (2.54mm pitch).
I tried to find specification for this type of ARM JTAG header and interface pinout table, but can't find anything. I find some description of another [device](http://rosincore.squarespace.com/storage/LP-JTAG.png) that based on same CPU, but its not too helpful.
Can anyone help to define a pinout for this type of JTAG connector? Or any specific implementation may not follow JTAG standard format?

[image]

Comment: There's no reason to assume it is a standard layout. You'll need to continuity test back to the chip or find a schematic to work out what does what.

Comment: "An embedded device" - Might help to mention what device in case anyone has experience or information with it.

Comment: Here is more detailed [pic.](http://cdn2.goughlui.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/2016021221172479.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't a standard JTAG pinout. If it is JTAG, though (which isn't a given), there are ways of mapping it out. For the sake of reference, let's number the pins:

```
7 8
5 6
3 4
1 2
```

Pin 8 is almost certainly ground -- it looks like it's connected to the ground plane.

Pins 3, 4, 5, and 6 look like they have resistors pulling them to ground. If I'm correct, this means they're inputs: they're likely to be some combination of TDI, TCK, TMS, and possibly TRST.

One of the remaining pins will be VCC. You should be able to find it by checking continuity to other known power nets on the board. Another one will be TDO; there's no obvious way to identify this one.

---

Beyond this, your best bet will be some combination of:

- Look up the pinout of the CPU and map out continuity to known JTAG pins on the chip.
- Guess a pin configuration, hook up a JTAG adapter, and see if it can pick anything up.
- Use a software tool like [JTAGenum](https://github.com/cyphunk/JTAGenum) to automate this guessing process.

Comment: Is it possible find pinout without a BSDL file?

Comment: @sonex Yes, using the methodology I laid out in my answer. You don't need a BSDL file to establish basic JTAG communications.

Comment: Note: I just find that this chip, implemented on another device, have JTAG pins TRST_N, TCK, RTCK, TMS, RST_N, TDO, TDI, GND, 1.8V. In case with my device, its JTAG interface may be  limited and have some of these pins not enabled?